Does a bijection between well orders of two sets imply a bijection between the sets?
We know that whether $|P(x)|=|P(y)|$ implies $|X|=|Y|$ is dependent on CH. Let $W(X)$ be the set of all well orders over $X$. Does $|W(X)|=|W(Y)|$ imply $|X|=|Y|$? Is the answer dependent on CH? More generally, what axioms do we need to show $|W(X)|=|P(X)|$? Is a bijection between them constructible?

What do you mean by 'constructible'?

Assuming $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$ we get that $|W(\omega)|=|W(\omega_1)|$.

$|W(0)|=|W(1)|$

Isn't $|P(X)|=|W(X)|$ just true in ZFC for all infinite $X$?

@AlessandroCodenotti It is, and the OP should know this from the answer to their previous question: https://mathoverflow.net/a/481412/ .

This question is similar to: How many well-orders of reals are there?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
